# Magento 2 “Recoverable Error: Argument 2 passed” when trying to define model in constructor

Tags: magento2, backend

Hi I have problem in Define model constructor,
This is my code:

```
<?php
namespace Retailers\Company\Model\Category;
use \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface;
class CategoryList implements ArrayInterface
{
protected $_categoryCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_categoryCollectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
}
public function toOptionArray($addEmpty = true)
{

    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection $collection */
    $collection = $this->_categoryCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');//->addRootLevelFilter()->load();
    $options = [];
    if ($addEmpty) {
        $options[] = ['label' => __('-- Please Select a Category --'), 'value' => ''];
    }
    foreach ($collection as $category) {
        $options[] = ['label' => $category->getName(), 'value' => $category->getId()];
    }
    return $options;
}
}
```

Comment: You probably need to recompile DI. Please post full exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just clear your cache and remove the generation/di folders.

- `cd /path/to/magento2`
- `rm -rf var/cache var/page_cache`
- `rm -rf var/generation var/di`